# Unix Time since Epoch, related to System Time?

Tags: web-services, security, timestamp

I would like to use the **[Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)** to avoid replay attacks to my web service. I would like the clients to add this value with the request amongst other security tokens. Then my server would also compute this value and accept what the client sent to me within a given error margin.
 Now, my question is this: If i tell my clients that i will accept an error margin of around 200. Less or greater than.

But can it really ever be greater than ? 
Also, does it depend on the system date-time settings of the client sending me the request ? 
Also, how do i decide an appropriate error margin so that i do not refuse genuine requests ?

Comment: As per Emil's answer, your methodology is fundamentally flawed. You could use the client clock drift as a short term solution for fingerprinting, but it's not clear from your post how your approach will improve security, not what threat models you are trying to address.

Comment: i thought i had mentioned `replay attacks` !!! whats up with the vote downs ? i am trying to do something similar to this: http://pusher.com/docs/rest_api. There are several other things i am putting into consideration like One-time dynamic security `tokens`, `cookies` and `hmac digests`. I only asked about the time stamp to understand how it would be useful for me to prevent `replay attacks`. The vote down was unnecessary

Comment: I guess the downvote is because you didn't state your question very well. It turned out that you wanted to know something different from what you asked. Note that I only answered your three questions in my original post. Actually, I thought you knew *why* the time was added in the first place and that you only had some small questions about it. (I am not the one downvoting, but not clearly stating your question can be a good reason to do it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*But can it really ever be greater than?*

Yes! You know nothing about the client clock. It may be minutes or hours wrong! You cannot trust the client clock anyway so I suggest you record the time in some sort of session on your server side and then do your calculations based on that.

*Also, does it depend on the system date-time settings of the client sending me the request?*

Yes. You can use the `Date.getUTCxxx()` functions in JS to get everything in the same timezone but you cannot trust the client to have a properly set clock.

*Also, how do i decide an appropriate error margin so that i do not refuse genuine requests?*

This depends on your service. Do you expect an immediate reply? Should the user do some work? Is it possible that the user loads a page and then leaves the computer to brew some nice, full roasted coffee for himself and his coworkers?

Comment: Thanks @Emil+Vikstrom. You are right. However, i have seen a certain Web service provider here: http://pusher.com/docs/rest_api  who asks us to add a timestamp using the `unix time since epoch`. I wonder how he uses it to prevent replay-attacks ?

Comment: It's there so the authentication signature changes for every request. You MUST couple it with some sort of signature for it to be meaningful. Note how the secret key (`7ad3773142a6692b25b8` in the example) is never sent along with the request. You need that secret to be able to generate a valid `auth_signature`. The timestamp is there so that old `auth_signatures` cannot be reused.

Comment: The unix time is sent along with the request. He doesn't check if it's different from previous requests, he just checks it against the server clock. The timestamp is included in the request so that the server knows what time was used to generated the `auth_signature`. He makes it the clients problem to ensure they are using the correct time.

Comment: +1, Thanks so much. That makes sense now. That was the answer i was looking for.